# Javascript redirect not working if i delete alert

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I have a function to redirect the page.
Function works perfectly when I have code like this.

```
document.getElementById("orderNow").addEventListener("click", function() {

// window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank";
var name = document.getElementById("customerName").textContent;
var address = document.getElementById("customerStreet").textContent;
var city = document.getElementById("customerCity").textContent;
var state = document.getElementById("customerState").textContent;
var zip = document.getElementById("customerPcode").textContent;
var country = document.getElementById("customerCountry").textContent;
var phone = document.getElementById("customerPhone").textContent;

window.location.href = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/addressselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1";


var username = document.getElementById('enterAddressFullName');


alert(username);
```

But if delete alert function or this:

```
var username = document.getElementById('enterAddressFullName');
```

Redirect won't work!

I don't know how to name the problem but this is my problem.
I don't want those last two lines of code. Help me to fix

Comment: What are you trying to do? Redirect to a new page? Is the redirect what is not working, or is it the alert after you redirect? If you redirect to a new page, how do you plan on doing the alert considering you have loaded a new page with new js? Also, please update your code above so that eventListener function is closed.

Comment: yes, Yes, get the some values from id and redirect to a url. i used the alert function to check did i get the value or not. then i delete the alert function because no need of that but after deleting the alert function, redirect is not working

Comment: Do you close your eventListener function? I can not see the closing )} in your code above. document.getElementById("orderNow").addEventListener("click", function() { .... your code here })

Comment: Yes my codes are there

Comment: Created a basic click event for you below that will do the redirect. Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a basic click event example for you below.

```js
let orderButtonEl = document.getElementById("orderNow").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // ... get all the values you need here and then do the redirect below

    alert("Click Event Working!!");

    // Redirect
    window.location.href = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/addressselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1";
});
```

```html
<button id="orderNow"> Order Now </button>
```

EDIT:
Not sure what you are doing, but copy the following and save it as an index.html file. Open it with chrome, click on the button and it will redirect you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="orderNow">
        Order Now
    </button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    let orderButtonEl = document.getElementById("orderNow").addEventListener("click", function() {

        // ... do stuff

        // Redirect
        window.location.href = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/addressselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1";
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. i am getting alert msg Click Event Working but not redirecting :-(

Comment: It will not redirect here, put the code in your project and test again.

Comment: I added the html file to my answer. If it is not working for you in your project, you have other issues too. I can not assist if you do not show me what is wrong.

Comment: Bro, anyway thanks for your code because i used it in another way (y)

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: Bro can you help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267742/firefox-addon-to-fill-input